# linuxserver.io/nextcloud switch db from sqlite

Tags: mysql, database, docker, sqlite, nextcloud

Im using the docker image linuxserver/nextcloud and im trying to switch my database from sqlite to mysql. Im really bad with databases so this might be a dumb question.

What i know is that i can use the occ to do that, but then im asked for a password of the db. The only thing i created was the admin account for the nextcloud, but that has nothing to do with this right?

I can use the cli inside my docker and after doing `sudo -u#1000 php occ db:convert-type --all-apps mysql abc 127.0.0.1 new_mysql_db` i get this

[SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UxXZI.png)

And i cant find anything like a standard db passwort on linuxserver/nextcloud docs.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the config.php from your nextcloud? For me the DB password is in there. This file is in the config directory of your nextcloud installation folder.